# Preserve disabled inputs in meteor

Tags: javascript, web-applications, data-binding, meteor, synchronization

I am currently designing an user-interface in [meteor](http://meteor.com/) with several text inputs whose contents are saved to session variables upon change (`keyup` event). Due to the `preserve-inputs` package, those input boxes are not re-rendered while they are in focus.

I have now tried to disable these input boxes by default and make them editable on double click (which might be a bad choice, but it is the simplest for the problem at hand and is sufficient for a first draft - maybe I'll ask over at UX later). However, when initially disabled, the input box is *not* preserved and re-rendered upon entry of a single character, disabling it again.

While it usually would not make sense to preserve a non-editable element from being re-rendered, I could not find anything in the code which would discriminate against the `disabled` state. So where is it, and how can I circumvent this? (I could, of course, set a `disabled` session variable on double-click/blur and re-render the input box in enabled state, but this seems overly complicated to me).

The following code (note that it is purely client-side JavaScript) reproduces this problem. It also renders a second input box which is never disabled, but is also only accessible after double-clicking. This works as intended without re-rendering. A live demo is deployed to http://preserve-disabled-inputs.meteor.com/.

`disabled.html`:

```
<head>
  <title>disabled</title>
</head>
<body>
  {{> body}}
</body>

<template name="body">
  <p>Double-click to enter text</p>
  {{> input f}}
  {{> input t}}
</template>

<template name="input">
  <div style="position: relative; width: 400px;">
    <input id="{{id}}" class="input" type="text" value="{{value}}" style="width: 100%;" {{disabled}}/>
    <!-- events on disabled inputs are not triggered -->
    <!-- overlay with transparent div to catch clicks -->
    <div class="catch" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;" />
  </div>
</template>
```

`disabled.js`:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // Setup for the example
  Session.setDefault('valuefalse', 'This one is preserved and can be edited without problems');
  Session.setDefault('valuetrue', 'This one is not preserved and loses focus on edit');

  Template.body.t = function() {
    return { disabled: true };
  }

  Template.body.f = function() {
    return { disabled: false };
  }

  Template.input.disabled = function() {
    return this.disabled ? 'disabled="disabled" ' : '';
  }

  Template.input.id = function() {
    return this.disabled ? 'd' : 'e';
  }

  Template.input.value = function() {
    return Session.get('value' + this.disabled);
  }

  // Here goes ...
  Template.input.events({
    'dblclick div.catch': function (evt) {
      var input = $('input.input', evt.target.parentNode);
      // Enable text box
      input.removeAttr('disabled');
      input.focus();
      // Don't render the div so the input box becomes accessible
      evt.target.style.display = 'none';
    },
    'keyup input.input': function (evt) {
      Session.set('value' + this.disabled, evt.target.value);
    },
    'blur input.input': function(evt) {
      // Re-render the catcher div
      $('div.catch', evt.target.parentNode).css('display', '');
      // Disable text box, if appliccable
      if (this.disabled) evt.target.disabled = 'disabled';
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: What is achieved by setting the `input` to be disabled in the first place? Especially if it’s editable on double-click. Maybe rather than adding the `disabled="disabled"` attribute you could just add `class="appear-disabled"` and style it to _look_ disabled, and then on double-click it toggles between appearing disabled and appearing active.

Comment: @GeoffreyBooth I guess I would have done something like this anyway; this was only a quick draft. Nonetheless, I'm curious why it behaves like this, even if it won't break the app. But, oh well.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the only working option is defining disabled="true", so the code would look like this:

```
disabled="{{#if isDisabled}}true{{/if}}"
```

Meteor will not even render/show the disabled tag (e.g. disabled="") in DOM if isDisabled is false.